# UIImage is showing on simulator, not on a real device

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have tried all of the suggestions in other similarly titled questions. My case seems to be special. Here's my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  if ([menu_List count] == 0){
      if (cell == nil) {
          cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
      }
        NSString *newString = [[MainMenuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
          UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", newString,@".png"]];
          UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
          [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 1.0, 41.0, 41.0)];
          [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
          [cell addSubview:imageView];

          cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

          GetData *GD = [[GetData alloc] init];
          cell.backgroundColor = [GD colorWithHexString:@"18204a"];
          cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [MainMenuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


    }else{

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [menu_List objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        GetData *GD = [[GetData alloc] init];
        cell.backgroundColor = [GD colorWithHexString:@"18204a"];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

So the string name is correct, and it matches the case. I've checked my build settings, and the images are in copy bundle resources. All show up in the simulator. Only two of the seven appear in the list. If I change the order in which they appear, it is still the same two images that show up. They all show up in the simulator. I am using ECSlidingViewController to create a menu and I want the images to show up. Any idea on what could be causing it?

Comment: remove the picture an re-add it.... it worked for me

Comment: Clean your project, then re-run on the device.  If you add resources you have to do a clean/rebuild for each new device you want to put it on.  Stupid, I know.

Comment: are you sure that your image is added to bundle?

Answer (score 2):

Clean your project and check for upper case letters. Simulator is not case sensitive, but real devices does not load an image if you use "myimage.png" on your code but your image name is MyImage.png

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your png is enabled for the schema